# How to Distribute a math expression without evaluating it

Tags: math, expression, simplify

I am attempting to create a linear combination of two numbers to create their GCD. The code I have so far can find the expanded solution. I have done all of the (hard) math for it (i.e. find the GCD using Euclid's Algorithm, then work backward essentially) and it will result in something like this for example (the two starting numbers are 1215 and 960):

`((960-(3*(1215-(1*960))))-(3*((1215-(1*960))-(1*(960-(3*(1215-(1*960))))))))`

In my actual solution there is a space between every component (e.g. '( ( 960 - (3 * '...)
but I am trying to simplify this into the equation:

`((-15*1215)+(19*960))`

I feel like the best approach is to create an Expression Tree, but I don't know how to without actually just evaluating the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a symbolic computation system. Here's one approach using Maxima (https://maxima.sourceforge.net). I'll enable `stardisp` to show `*` between terms of a product. I'll also input numbers like `960` as symbols in order to suppress arithmetic on them by writing them as `\960` etc. Note that `1` and `3` are input as ordinary numbers so arithmetic is carried out on them.

```
(%i13) stardisp:true;
(%o13)                        true
(%i14) 2*3;
(%o14)                          6
(%i15) \2*\3;
(%o15)                         2*3
(%i16) ((\960-(3*(\1215-(1*\960))))-(3*((\1215-(1*\960))-(1*(\960-(3*(\1215-(1*\960))))))));
(%o16) 960 - 3*(1215 - 960) - 3*((- 2*960) + 3*(1215 - 960)
                                                          + 1215)
(%i17) factor(%);
(%o17)                  19*960 - 15*1215
```

Maybe you want to replace the numbers with symbols `a`, `b`, `c`, etc to get a more general solution.

There are many other symbol computation systems, a web search will find them. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: I didn't think about substituting it with variables, duhh!! Thanks!!